# How to create oauth HMAC-SHA2 signature for facebook

Tags: c++, facebook-oauth

For google i found google oauth playground for creating the  oauth signature.

Can anyone of you suggest any nice tutorials or suggest how to create one for facebook

Thanks in advance

Comment: where do you want to use oAuth ? iOS App ? Web App ? iOS app SDK of Facebook includes library to create oAuth HMAC-SHA2 .

Comment: I am having a native application in C++. How can i do it without using library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook is not expecting oauth signature parameters